# How to make blog post entries appear as input form instead of just text?

Tags: php, forms, blog, text, input

I want my blog posts to appear inside of a form input box instead of just text on a page. Not the title, but only the submission. Is that possible.

My index.php:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b>
=               <div class="entry">
                    <?php the_content('Read more &raquo;'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
<form action="demo_form.php">
  <textarea name="blogpost" readonly="readonly">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: this works. but the blog posts shows the html tags for example <p> when there is a new paragraph. Is there any way around that?

Comment: so you want a wysiwyg editor?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want the Post content to be used as a placeholder text in a forms text box?

I guess you could do something like this if that is what you are trying to do..

```
<?php $content = the_content(); ?>

<form action="demo_form.php">
  <input type="text" name="postvalue" placeholder="<?php echo $content ?>">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I want my posts to appear like this http://jsfiddle.net/skootsa/vqLvquhe/ I just don't want viewers to be able to change the placeholder.

Comment: use this then in the form.

    <textarea name="blogpost" readonly="readonly" placeholder="<?php the_content(); ?>">
        
    </textarea>